# openMP deadlock while using parallel region and open for together

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, deadlock

I am running into an openMP deadlock. The original code is relatively long and  difficult to put here due to
space constraints. I include a example of code structure, which seemingly has similar structure and runs 
into similar issues.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

        if(thread_id>0)
        {
            #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) nowait
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                printf("%dth hello from thread \t: %d\n",i,thread_id );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("=========Master thread \t: %d ==============\n",thread_id );
        }
            }

    printf(" +=*+=*+=*+=*+=*+=*+=*+=*+=*+=*+=*\n");
    #pragma omp parallel 
    {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

        if(thread_id>0)
        {
            #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) nowait
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                printf("%dth hello from thread \t: %d\n",i,thread_id );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("=========Master thread \t: %d==============\n ",thread_id );
        }
}

    return 0;
}
```

I intend to use first thread to do a computation, while I want to utilize other threads to concurrently 
execute a openmp parallel for loop. The code hangs while executing openmp parallel region. If I intruppt the program 
in GDB, I see following message.

```
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x000000327c00b5bc in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

I need to know if what I am trying to do is valid and possible. If so, what is possible work
arounds to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you are doing is not valid according to the [OpenMP specification](http://openmp.org/wp/openmp-specifications/) (OpenMP version 3.1, §2.5 Worksharing Constructs):

> **Restrictions**:
>
> The following restrictions apply to worksharing constructs:
>
> - *Each worksharing region must be encountered by all threads in a team or by none at all.*

(emphasis mine) This changes a bit in OpenMP 4.0 with the introduction of cancellation points, but the general idea remains the same.

But since you are using `schedule(dynamic)` which defaults to a chunk size of one iteration, you can use explicit tasks instead:

```c
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
   #pragma omp section
   {
      printf("This is a single thread doing something\n");
   }
   #pragma omp section
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
         #pragma omp task
         {
            int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
            printf("%d-th hello from thread %d\n", i, thread_id);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

You could also implement your own sections like you've done in your original code and you could also reimplement static scheduling (if necessary) by using the thread IDs to compute the iteration range.